# Run-time error 1004 when copy/pasting cells in same active sheet

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

Wrote the code below to check if two cells are the same.  The cell in column 20 is a vlookup that returns comments from another sheet.  I want to check if the cell in column 16 has those comments already and, if it does not, I want the macro to paste values from the cell in 20 to the cell in 16.  I'm basically doing this because I want the comments in 16 to be just the pure text but it needs to dynamically (via another macro) update as the comments are related to a pivot table that they sit next to on the sheet.

Edit: I'm using Excel 2007 in case it's relevant.

In the code below, the problem shows up when the macro tries to copy the cell in column 20. 
This code specifically:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(rowstest, 20)).Copy
```

Here is the full code:

```
Sub MgrCmntsTest()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rowstest As Integer
    rowstest = 1
    Dim comments As String
    Dim commentsForm As String
    With ActiveSheet.Range("a1:u500")
        Do
        comments = Cells(rowstest, 20).Value
        commentsForm = Cells(rowstest, 16).Value
        If comments = commentsForm Then
            rowstest = rowstest + 1
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(rowstest, 20)).Copy
            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(rowstest, 16)).Select
            ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Type:=xlPasteValues
            rowstest = rowstest + 1
        End If
        Loop While rowstest < 501
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `ActiveSheet.Cells(rowstest, 20).Copy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you could reduce the code to

```
Range("p1:P500").Value = Range("T1:T500").Value
```

*(as the values need to be copied if they are different, and the values can still be copied over if they are the same)*

Comment: Well now you've made me feel like an idiot, haha.

Thanks for the response and that works beautifully!